# How to inject script with relative path to html using javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got a problem when I was trying to inject script to html page using javascript. This script have to be set with relative path just like it was into my cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    @{
        if (Request["debug"] != "false")
        {
            <script src='~/Scripts/script-first-debug.js'></script>
            <script src='~/Scripts/script-second-debug.js'></script>
        }
        else
        {
            <script src='~/Scripts/script-first.js'></script>
            <script src='~/Scripts/script-second.js'></script>
        }
    }

</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

and it's part of my typescript file where I moved this .net case from cshtml file:

```
var scriptFirst = document.createElement('script');
var striptSecond = document.createElement('script');

scriptFirst.type = 'text/javascript';
striptSecond.type = 'text/javascript';

scriptFirst.src = this.debug ? '/Scripts/script-first-debug.js' : '/Scripts/script-first.js';
striptSecond.src = this.debug ? '/Scripts/script-second-debug.js' : '/Scripts/script-second.js';

$('head').append(scriptFirst).append(striptSecond);
```

On localhost everything is good but when this code has been deployed on my production instance of application then I've got a problem. On my production application instance I add to address some string. For example:

On localhost the path to script-first.js is: https://localhost:80/Scripts/script-first.js

On production the path to this file is like that:
https://www.myproblematicapplication.com/someString/Scripts/script-first.js

Have you got any tips how can I to do it?
I was trying to find some solutions on stack overflow and on other pages but unfortunetly without success yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relative path points to the root folder (DOCROOT/document root) that is hosted at that host (www.myproblematicapplication.com). But the files are not in that folder. To fix this, assuming the files are in the same folder as your typescript file that adds them to the application:

**Change:**

```
'/Scripts/script-first-debug.js'
```

**To:**

```
'./Scripts/script-first-debug.js'
```

in all URLs.

Note the leading dot. This says "find these files in the same folder relative to this file".